# stl remove_if with class member function result

Tags: stl, containers, functor

I have a object container, list; and class Foo have a member function id() return an integer identifier.
Now I want to use stl algorithm remove_if to remove some objects whose id is less than a value.
**I don't want to provide a function for id compare**, If it is possible for me to write  one line code with STL but boost to implement it.

```
class Foo{
public:
  unsigned id() const {return id_;}
  ...
private:
  unsigned id_
  ...
};
list<Foo> foo_list;
std::remove_if(foo_list.begin(), foo_list.end(), ???);
```

If STL can do this with only std::bind2nd, stl::less(), std::mem_fun_ref() or other stl functions.

Comment: If you have a modern enough compiler, look up [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I use vs2005, without C++11 support.

Comment: Well, you're on the right track with those 3 std helpers, but unfortunately C++ doesn't include SGI's compose function adaptors. So you won't get around your own functor. That's exactly why C++11's lambdas (and generalized binders) improve the standard algorithms' useability that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible to achieve without lambdas, if you agree to change the interface of `Foo` a little bit.

```
class Foo
  {
public:
  Foo(unsigned id)
    : id_(id) {}
  bool is_equal(unsigned id) const
    { return id_ == id; }
private:
  unsigned id_;
  };

typedef list<Foo> FooList;

FooList foo_list;
foo_list.push_back(Foo(1));
foo_list.push_back(Foo(2));

unsigned to_remove = 1;
foo_list.remove_if(std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun_ref(&Foo::is_equal), to_remove));
```