# Whats the cleanest way to compare to the result of a member function call

Tags: generics, boost, stl, functor

Forgive me if this has been asked before, I'm just unable to find an appropriate solution.

I often find myself creating functors for member functions of a class like the following to use for find_if or remove_if afterwards

```
class by_id{
  public:
    by_id(int id):mId(id) {}

    template <class T>
    bool operator()(T const& rX) const { return rX.getId() == mId; }

    template <class T>
    bool operator()(T* const pX) const { return (*this)(*pX); }

  private:
    int mId;
};
```

While this works fine it contains a lot of boilerplate and means to define a class for every member function I want to use for comparison.

I know about lambdas in C++11 but I cannot switch to the new standard due to cross-compiler restrictions.

The closest related question I have found is [stl remove_if with class member function result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922814/484230) but the given solution means adding additional member functions for comparison, which is ugly.

Isn't there any easier way using standard STL or perhaps boost to write such functors in a more generic way or to use bind to skip them altogether ?

Something like a generic functor would do, but I lack the skill to write it. 
Just to make clear what I have in mind:

```
  template<typename FP,typename COMP>
  class by_id{
      public:
        by_id(COMP id):mId(id) {}

        template <class T>
        bool operator()(T const& rX) const { return rX.FP() == mId; } 
        //of course this does not work

        template <class T>
        bool operator()(T* const pX) const { return (*this)(*pX); }

      private:
        COMP mId;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know `T` ahead of time (at the creation of `by_id` objects, you can make that a template parameter of `by_id` and pass a pointer to a member function to the constructor.  Something like:

```
template<typename T, typename COMP>
class by_id
{
 public:
  typedef COMP (T::*MemFunc)();
  by_id(COMP id, MemFunc mf) : mId(id), mmf(mf) {}

  bool operator()(T const& rX) const { return rX.*mmf() == mId; }

 private:
  COMP mId;
  MemFunc mmf;
};
```

Comment: Thanks again for the valuable advice. That was exactly what I was looking for. Why is such thing not part of some library, it seems pretty handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a member function pointer to the comparer to indicate which value to compare on.

Using a `make_comparer` function to avoid having to specify type parameters at point of use ( similar to `std::make_pair` )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, typename R>
class comparer
{
public:
    typedef R ( T::*accessor_type ) () const;
    typedef R value_type;
    comparer ( accessor_type accessor, value_type value ) :
        accessor_ ( accessor ), value_ ( value ) { }

    accessor_type accessor_;
    value_type value_;

    bool operator() ( T const& rX ) const {
        return ( rX.*accessor_ ) () == value_;
    }
    bool operator() ( const T* pX ) const {
        return ( *this ) ( *pX );
    }
};

template <typename T, typename R>
comparer<T, R> make_comparer ( R ( T::*accessor ) () const, R value )
{
    return comparer<T, R> ( accessor, value );
}

class Foo
{
public:
    explicit Foo ( int id, int rank ) : id_ ( id ), rank_ ( rank ) { }
private:
    int id_, rank_;

public:
    int id() const {
        return id_;
    }
    int rank() const {
        return rank_;
    }

};

std::vector<Foo> foos;
typedef std::vector<Foo>::const_iterator FooIT;

void print ( FooIT it )
{
    if ( it == foos.end() )
        std::cout << "no match" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "matches id: " << it -> id () << " rank: " << it -> rank () << std::endl;
}

main()
{

    foos.push_back ( Foo ( 1, 3 ) );
    foos.push_back ( Foo ( 2, 2 ) );
    foos.push_back ( Foo ( 3, 1 ) );

    std::cout << "compare id == 2 ";
    print ( std::find_if ( foos.begin(), foos.end(), make_comparer ( &Foo::id, 2 ) ) );

    std::cout << "compare id == 3 ";
    print ( std::find_if ( foos.begin(), foos.end(), make_comparer ( &Foo::id, 3 ) ) );

    std::cout << "compare rank == 3 ";
    print ( std::find_if ( foos.begin(), foos.end(), make_comparer ( &Foo::rank, 3 ) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace boost;
std::find_if(first, last, bind(std::equal<int>(), bind(&Foo::getId, _1), id));
```

This creates a nested bind expression and calls it for each element in the range `[first,last)`, where calling the bind expression for an element `Foo i` is equivalent to calling:

```
std::equal<int>()( i.getId(), id )
```

i.e. it tests if `i.getId()` is equal to `id`

In C++11 you could replace `boost::bind` with `std::bind`

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::find_if(first, last, std::bind(std::equal<int>(), std::bind(&Foo::getId, _1), id));
```